# Powershell Redirect Script Output

Tags: powershell, redirect, dependencies, output

I have two Powershell scripts - the first script which we will call Script_A, calls the second script which we'll call Script_B. Both scripts can be summarised as follows:

Script_A - Calls Script_B, passing some parameters in the process, For example:

```
.\Script_B.ps1 $Param1 $Param2
```

Script_B - Executes a powershell function and other logic, by consuming the two parameters issued by Script_A, i.e. $Param1 and $Param2

What I'd like to do now is redirect the results displayed on the console to an output file. I've tried everything from using the Out-File cmdlet and also the redirect character '>>' but still can't get the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is `Script_B.ps1` currently outputting to the console? Using `Write-Host`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen you're spot-on. Script_B.ps1 currently outputs to the console using Write-Host.

Answer (score 0):

When you have Powershell, you should avoid using console output as input as much as possible.

Example of calling Script2 from Script1 here. Script2 returns powershell object back to Script1 and this is not "dumb string" - it is structured data you don't need to parse.

```
#SCRIPT1.ps1
$Param1 = 'Jane'
$Param2 = 'Don Pedro'
$result = & 'D:\Script2.ps1' -Name $Param1 -Surname $Param2
$result | ConvertTo-Json | Out-String

#SCRIPT2.ps1
Param(
    [String]$Name,
    [String]$Surname)
return [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name = $Name.ToLowerInvariant(); 
    Surname = $Surname.ToUpperInvariant(); 
    ID = (Get-Random)}
```